# How to get the last preg_match function result in a string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string as:

```
$string='Di Cioccio v Official Trustee in Bankruptcy (as Trustee of the Bankrupt Estate of Di Cioccio) (FCAFC) - bankruptcy - shares were after-acquired property which vested in Official Trustee (I B C G)';
```

I am using preg_match() function to get the value within parenthesis as:

```
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $string, $match);
```

However, the problem here is "echo $match[0]" will display only the first match in the string.

I want to get the last match ie. "I B C G"

First thought I have is to search from the end of the string. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find all matches from `preg_match`, then may I present to you [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all)?

It has basically the same syntax as the other function, but will explicitly find all matches in the string rather than just the first. After that, it's simply a matter of `echo end($match);` to get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @xathien code I sorted this issue and the code is as follows:

```
$string='Di Cioccio v Official Trustee in Bankruptcy (as Trustee of the Bankrupt Estate of Di Cioccio) (FCAFC) - bankruptcy - shares were after-acquired property which vested in Official Trustee (I B C G)';
preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)#', $string, $match);
echo end($match[1]);
```

Displays: 
I B C G